# Timer triggered Azure function Activity.Current is null

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, availability

**Scenario**

I have followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/availability-azure-functions) and created `azure function v3` in `net core 3.1` to monitor my web application. U used Visual Studio instead of developing it in the portal.

**Problem**

Unfortunately i received `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.get returned null.` in line:

```
availability.Context.Operation.ParentId = Activity.Current.SpanId.ToString();
```

How to fix that?

Comment: May I ask a question that why you wanna follow this tutorial to enable monitor? In my opinion, if you''d like to create a function to monitor your web app, you can just enable app insights when creating azure function and it will provide many features to capture telemetry from function.

Comment: It enable to set availabilitynij azure. Simple ping is not enough for my application. I need to know if my authorized request with sent file is properly executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... I think the tutorial may have some error on the code, and we can comment the two lines where error took place.

This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activity?view=net-5.0#remarks) said :

> Activities should be created by calling the constructor, configured as
> necessary, and then started with the Start method, which maintains
> parent-child relationships for the activities and sets
> Activity.Current.

and this is why `availability.Context.Operation.ParentId = Activity.Current.SpanId.ToString();` burst an error. And focus on this line-code,
does this line make sense? So in my test, I made this line and the line behind it commented, and code executed well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This answer is not complete. Using this example the telemetry id is left empty.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same tutorial to set up availability tests with Azure Function.

First, deleting these two lines will solve the error and the function will work

```
availability.Context.Operation.ParentId = Activity.Current.SpanId.ToString(); 
availability.Context.Operation.Id = Activity.Current.RootId;
```

But in this way, with `availability.Id = Activity.Current.SpanId.ToString();` The availability.Id sent to logs in application insight will always be `0000000000000`. If you are not concerned with giving each availability test a unique ID, that's fine.

If you want, you can add a custom ID or identifier in
`availability.Message` in json format.

Comment: "If you want"? Do You know what is the "good" way Microsoft suggest it to do it?